# Maple tree's new-sprouting branches

Tags: trees, pruning, maple

40 year old Maple tree is sprouting new branches. Should they be cut off or allowed to grow ? How can I send you a photo?

Answer (score 0):

Many old trees have new shoots. I would prune them as earlier as possible, but if the main trunk is not so healthy and you want to replace it.

Note: because these shoots shares (get) the resource of the entire plant roots (many roots, some also deep), they tend also to grow very quickly.